# Fill in gaps on our covered porch!

Tags: porch, gap

We just had a nightmare encounter with a contractor, but I'll skip the deets and get to my new problem- He did a lousy job that left us with many gaps where the framing for the screens didn't sit square with the beams for the porch. Most of these gaps are 1.5" -> 3/4", so not huge but significant.

What're my best options for filling these in? An army of shims? Expanding foam? Something else? Images below.

[image: gap]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Nightmare encounter" indicates that you're done trying to get him to fix his shoddy workmanship? I'd be sure to hit every social website known to man to post these pics along with a bad review. It's the only way... :(

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the screens are permanent, you could just add some overlapping trim boards to cover the gap (on both sides). Then all you see is the nice neat edges of the trim. For the part by siding, you could similarly "side" the new wood with cut-to-fit overlapping column of cedar shakes or something like that. Just an idea. I think foam would be messy to apply and look bad.

Comment: I would suggest a bead of caulk under each edge of the trim (against the original house side and against the new screen side) to help keep the little critters on the outside (I'd presume that's the purpose of all the screening). The wall could be trimmed with a scribed piece that fits the profile of the siding on one side and is straight on the other.

Answer (score 2):

The deck has to slope from home to the outside end.

Your contractor just put a 2x6 straight (leveled) so installing the net would be easy for him.

Filling the gap with foam will not look well but it can be done if you decide so. Foam will absorb the moisture and allow for fungus to grow.

Installing trim boards would work, but since the deck and the 2x6 are not parallel it will show.

The most work intensive would be to measure and cut pieces of 2x6 and insert/glue into gaps. It would require a table saw for cutting.

Comment: "Foam will absorb the moisture and allow for fungus to grow." [Citation needed] as I've not experienced that even in spray foam exposed to the outside for 10+ years. Didn't look pretty, but never saw fungus.

Comment: Open cell foam will absorb water, closed cell won't. Most foams like 'Great Stuff' that are designed for sealing up houses are going to be closed cell. I suppose you should still consider if water could get around or sit on top of the foam, but generally it's not going to be a problem.